# Asynchronous Audio file upload with iOS

Tags: iphone, file, asynchronous, upload

is there a way to upload an audiofile to my server asynchronously? I implemented it synchronously using the NSURLConnection class already.

Maybe you could also give me a short code example.

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You absolutely have to use **ASIHttpRequest**.

It is astoundingly easy - it's the most popular library on all of iOS.

Just select the "asynchronous" mode.

It is almost impossibly easy to use.  Basically just type in the URL.

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Enjoy!

---

It's stunning news that Ben no longer does ASIHttpRequest !

You can read all about it here:

http://allseeing-i.com/[request_release];

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I set it up correctly and i do get a response from the server so far. I wanted to send `NSData` but `[request addPostValue:file forKey:@"file"];` did not work for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks, `setData` did it for me. Unfortunately I can't upvote as I need 15 rep points );

Answer (score 2):

The [`NSURLConnection`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) will allow you to upload the file asynchronously as well. There are delegate methods that will be called you on your class . Use the [`NSMutableURLRequest`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to create your upload request the follow the following guide.

[URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE)

Answer (score 0):

It's 2015. iOS 9.1 was just released. AFNetworking has become the most popular library for handling HTTP requests. [It supports asynchronous file uploads](https://github.com/afnetworking/afnetworking#creating-an-upload-task). Here's an example:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/upload"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"file://path/to/image.png"];
NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromFile:filePath progress:nil completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Success: %@ %@", response, responseObject);
    }
}];
[uploadTask resume];
```