# how to upload audio from iphone to web server?

Tags: iphone

I am designing application that record sound then save it then upload it from iphone to a web server

but the problem here is i don't know how to upload audio from iphone to web server ? any can help plz?

thanks in advence

Comment: Is your recording part working? You'll need to find an HTTP library that will let you make POST requests.  That will probably be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Asynchronous Audio file upload with iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478174/asynchronous-audio-file-upload-with-ios)